# refresh current page after set timeout function call

Tags: jquery, settimeout

Is there a way to refresh page after `setTimeout()` function call is executed?

here is the code of setTimeout function call:

```
setTimeout(function(){
     $('#alert-success').slideUp('slow').fadeOut();
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

try with

```
setTimeout(function(){
     $('#alert-success').slideUp('slow').fadeOut(function() {
         window.location.reload();
         /* or window.location = window.location.href; */
     });
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do like this:
(when you use `.slideUp`, there is no need to use `.fadeOut`)

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $('#alert-success').slideUp('slow', window.location.reload);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this below

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
    function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
//   -->
</script>
</head>

<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(5000);">
    <p>This page will refresh every 5 seconds. This is because we're using the 'onload' event to call our function. We are passing in the value '5000', which equals 5 seconds.</p>
    <p>But hey, try not to annoy your users too much with unnecessary page refreshes every  few seconds!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I already found the solution from Fabrizio :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also Use

```
window.location.href = window.location.href
```

Script rewritten as

```
setTimeout(function()
{

    $('#alert-success').slideUp('slow').fadeOut();
    window.location.href = window.location.href

},5000)
```